# Login with linq with login (array) list dataset in another c# file

Tags: c#, linq, list, class, namespaces

So I have a .cs class page storage.cs I have put my student array details in this page as you can see. I would like to use this as my datasource/database for student login details.

I would like to query this array List in login.cs. Basically I would like to check if username and password match (in login.cs), so the user can login. How can I access this student list in another file and be abel to use it.

```
storage.cs

namespace Program1
{
public class class2
{
    public class Person
    {
        // Member Variables

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student : Person //student inherits from Person class
    {
        public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string AwardID { get; set; }
        public string[] modules { get; set; }


    }



        public void allStudents(string User_name, string _password)
        {

            List<Student> st = new List<Student>{
        new Student { StudentNumber="CE52103-2", 
            FirstName ="AAA", 
            LastName = "BBB", 
            UserName = "CCC",
            Password ="DDD", 
            DateOfBirth = "",
            Gender ="",
            AwardID =""},


        new Student { StudentNumber="CE52603-2", 
            FirstName ="BBB", 
            LastName = "DDD" , 
            UserName = "FFF",
            Password ="GGG", 
            DateOfBirth = "",
            Gender = "",
            AwardID =""},

        new Student { StudentNumber="CE52302-2", 
            FirstName ="GGG", 
            LastName = "HHH", 
            UserName = "KKK",
            Password ="LLL", 
            DateOfBirth = "",
            Gender ="",
            AwardID =""},
        };


        }
}
```

}

Here is what I have tried to do in my login.cs on button click event but doesn't work. I am pretty new to c# so p'se do not laugh.

```
   login.cs

         protected void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {
    Program1.class2.Student bb_ = new Program1.class2.Student();



    List<Student> st = new List<Student>();// I dont know how to acces this List :(

    st.Add(new Student
    {
        UserName = _username,
        Password = _password,

    });

    var stquery = (from Student student in st
                   where student.UserName.Equals(_username) &&
                   student.Password.Equals(_password)
                   select student).FirstOrDefault();

    if (stquery == null)
    {
        //Login failded
    }
    else
    {
        //Login successful
    }

 }
```

I really am stuck at this. I can use a database easily but the assignment doesn't allow us to. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Thank you @Pedro, at the moment, I cant seem to be able to create the instance of a class. What reference do I have to add to the current page where I am querying from? At the moment, this the error I get "The type or namespace name'Student' could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference".

Comment: Remove the wrapping class `class2`. It's useless. This is a javascript-surrogate for a namespace.

Comment: Thank you once again @Pedro, but I still have problems. I have tried the two approaches you've suggested, they both have failed to work. I have separated the two classes in different files. My guess is that the problem is with the ".allStudents();". Which ever way I do it. I get this error 'Student does not contain a definition for "allStudents" and no extension method "allStudents" accepting a first argument of type Student'; Am nearer to giving up :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the signature in your class to return yous student something like this:

```
public List<Student> allStudents(string User_name, string _password)
{
        List<Student> st = new List<Student>{
        new Student { StudentNumber="CE52103-2", 
            FirstName ="AAA", 
            LastName = "BBB", 
            UserName = "CCC",
            Password ="DDD", 
            DateOfBirth = "",
            Gender ="",
            AwardID =""},

        new Student { StudentNumber="CE52603-2", 
            FirstName ="BBB", 
            LastName = "DDD" , 
            UserName = "FFF",
            Password ="GGG", 
            DateOfBirth = "",
            Gender = "",
            AwardID =""},

        new Student { StudentNumber="CE52302-2", 
            FirstName ="GGG", 
            LastName = "HHH", 
            UserName = "KKK",
            Password ="LLL", 
            DateOfBirth = "",
            Gender ="",
            AwardID =""},
        };
       return st;
}
```

then you need to create an instance of your class student to access the list 
in your login page

**Edit:**
you can declare your class student outside class2 and create the instances in this way:

```
 Student student = new Student();
    list<Student> studentList = student.allStudents();
```

or try with this if you're using nested classes

```
 Program1.class2.Student student = new Program1.class2.Student();
    list<Program1.class2.Student> studentList = student.allStudents();
```

then you are going to be able to do a linq through that list

```
var stquery = (from var s in studentList
                   where s.UserName.Equals(_username) &&
                   s.Password.Equals(_password)
                   select s).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you @Pedro, at the moment, I cant seem to be able to create the instance of a class. What reference do I have to add to the current page where I am querying from? At the moment, this the error I get "The type or namespace name'Student' could not be found, are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference".

Comment: remove the class2 that you have as a wrapper, separate each class in different files

Answer (score 0):

Solved, First of all thank you @Pedro for a your help, just needed to twitch it a little by writing the login method in the class file and then calling for that method in the login.cs. 
here is my final code just in case anybody might find it useful.

```
 class3.cs

  public class Class3
  {
     public static List<_Student> st = new List<_Student>
     {

    new _Student { StudentNumber="CE52103-2", 
        FirstName ="AAA", 
        LastName = "BBB", 
        UserName = "CCC",
        Password ="DDD", 
        DateOfBirth = "",
        Gender ="",
        AwardID =""},

    new _Student { StudentNumber="CE52603-2", 
        FirstName ="BBB", 
        LastName = "DDD" , 
        UserName = "FFF",
        Password ="GGG", 
        DateOfBirth = "",
        Gender = "",
        AwardID =""},

    new _Student { StudentNumber="CE52302-2", 
        FirstName ="GGG", 
        LastName = "HHH", 
        UserName = "KKK",
        Password ="LLL", 
        DateOfBirth = "",
        Gender ="",
        AwardID =""}

        //return st;
    };

 public static void login( string username, string password)
 {
     var stquery = (from s in st
                    where s.UserName.Equals(username) &&
                   s.Password.Equals(password)
                    select s).FirstOrDefault();

     if (stquery == null)
     {
         //Login failded redirect to registration
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("registration.aspx");

     }
     else
     {
         //Login successful redirect to manager
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");
     }

  }
 }
```

Then this is my class2.cs

```
class2.cs //getters and setters

   public class Person
    {
        // Member Variables

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

    public class _Student : Person //student inherits from Person class
    {
        public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string AwardID { get; set; }
        public string[] modules { get; set; }


    }
```

And lastly here is how I call for the login method in the login.cs

```
   public partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page
{


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {


}
protected void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Class3.login(TextBoxLoginUser.Text, TextBoxLoginPass.Text);




 }
}
```

Hope it helps someone out there :).

Comment: Still don't understand these nested classes. They're public, so the nesting is utterly useless.